# 1970s show with an oil painting of a man in a row boat, painting changes and the man is closer

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, episode-identification

So the oil painting is hung on the staircase so every time they (a blond guy maybe and a wife?) walk up the stairs, he looks at the painting and notices the man's boat is closer.  The painting changes several times until the boat is docked on the bay and there's a knock on the door.  I believe the man/ghost is a soldier.  I suspect it could be a Night Gallery episode?  Along that genre anyway, thanks for the info!

Comment: I don't have an answer, but _The Night Gallery_ is being rerun on MeTV.  If you're in the U.S. and have that network on your cable system, you might find it in the re-runs.

Answer (score 6):

I believe you are seeking the the Night Gallery Pilot episode from 1969.  The Segment was called: "The Escape Route".

A Nazi war criminal (Richard Kiley) is hiding from the authorities in South America, where he is confronted with his past demons and a curious Holocaust survivor (Sam Jaffe) and finds solace only in a serene painting in a museum, wanting nothing more than to enter into that world and stop running.

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0064725/plotsummary

Comment: This.  Though i'm thinking of the episode about a guy that locked someone in a mausoleum, and the painting this guy made slowly changed to show the dead person coming out and eventually killed

Comment: These all could be possibilities...I remember the painting on the wall to the right going up stairs at a home though - not a museum?  Thanks for all the info.